# Is there a way I can subtract two columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query with columns Date (Ex: 2020-03-31 00:00:00:000),Time_in (9:38),Time_out (11:38).

```
select *,date_time_in - date_time_out from 
(select Date,Time_in,Time_out , 
convert(varchar,date,111) + ' ' + time_in as date_time_in ,
convert(varchar,date,111) + ' ' + time_out as date_time_out 
from abc) X
```

Can I do a subtract operator to get the difference between the two new alias columns I created for example 9:38 - 11:38 ?

Comment: Have you taken a look on DATEDIFF-function?

Comment: I did but I found it quite confusing to work with this query.

Comment: it would be nice to see sample data and required result

Comment: `convert(varchar,date,111) + ' ' + time_in ` won't work either. You'll get an error telling you that `varchar` and `time` are incompatible for the add operator.

Comment: *"I did but I found it quite confusing to work with this query. "* What part of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) confused you? It includes lots of [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) on how to use it; what about those examples didn't you understand?

Comment: @larnu I did not find it at for this since it is a date/time to a character string

Comment: @Alice no, you can't "add" a `time` and a `varchar`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=96f33fdda32a5415b9200f01c3c9ee95)

Comment: (Ex: 2020-03-31 00:00:00:000),Time_in (9:38),Time_out (11:38)
convert(varchar,date,111) + ' ' + time_in  this worked though  with output 
2020/03/31 9:38

Comment: Then `time_out` is *not* a `time`, @Alice. That's a design flaw you need to fix.

Comment: @Alice there's nothing confusing about `datediff(s,time_out,time_in)`. This query though is *very* confusing - dates aren't strings. You can't calculated the difference between strings

Answer (score 1):

Assuming **Time_In** and **Time_Out** are columns in table **abc**, the following code will give you the difference in seconds between the two values.

```
select *, DATEDIFF(second, Time_In, Time_Out) AS DateDiff from abc
```